# why my card is not getting aligned horizontally

Tags: html, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-cards

here is the code for the card section. The cards get down added vertically when added i want them to be horizontally aligned , 3 cards in one row . please  help. Thanks a lot

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          </div>
          <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
          </ul>
          <div class="card-body">
            <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
            <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
           
            <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
              </div>
              <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
              </ul>
              <div class="card-body">
                <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
              </div>
            </div>
             
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          </div>
          <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
          </ul>
          <div>
            <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
            <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
      </div>
      <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
      </ul>
      <div>
        <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
        <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
      </div>                 
    </div>
  </div>
       
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          </div>
          <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
          </ul>
          <div>
            <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
            <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the structure for alignment.
[image]

Comment: its working can you please explain what you did?

Comment: actually, you added a second column inside the first column I just updated your structure and that worked.

Comment: hey , 2 cards are getting aligned 3rd one is not getting aligned

Comment: hey I did add the structure hope you got my point.

Comment: i got your point , i did the same thing but the 3rd card is getting below the 2nd card and not horizontally

Comment: okay can you update the code in question so I can check what's wrong?

Comment: yes , have a look i'm updating

Comment: it shows ome error while i edit it

Comment: what i did was just copy/pasted the 2nd card code one more time

Comment: worry not i update code for three cards in my answer have a look it works fine for me

Comment: My laptop died , I'll revert back after making the changes . Thanks a lot though

Comment: hey , 3 cards are working perfectly fine. Thanks a lot for helping me out and sorry for replying this late